# How authorization attribute call authentication middle ware in DotNet Core?

Tags: authentication, .net-core, authorization

What are the relationships between authorization attribute and authentication middleware in DotNet Core ? Which one calls another one?

Comment: I debug dotnet core source code, I could not understand what happend,I put AllowAnonymous attribute on action and debug the source code,authentication middleware again calls In asp mvc lifecycle attribute was clear but in dot net core and middleware authorization attribute are unclear for me.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2

I have read this article and searched a lot.

Authorization attribute and authentication middleware are completetly seperate.
I was confused.

Middlewares are applied to all request and attribute just apply in specefic controllers and actions